# Will I be able to update WordPress Paid theme if I change theme name from style.css file?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Suppose I've installed BE Theme in wordpress. If I change default theme name and other author info from style.css file, will I be able to get automatic updates later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress update system uses theme/plugin directory name/main file as slug for checking updates.

It means that you can change the values inside style.css and you'll still be able to check and perform updates (as long, as the name of directory stays unchanged).

On the other hand, there are two problems with such change:

1. These values will get restored after every update.
2. It's unethical. You're not the author of that theme and it's not your theme, so you shouldn't make your clients think otherwise. And if that theme is under GPL, then it's against its license.

But... You can (and you should) create a child theme and you can put whatever info you want in there.